# How to remove the `CPU NN%` text from load indicator

Tags: desktop-environments, 16.04

I just installed the ubuntu 16.04 alpha desktop and after an hour or so a strange label appeared near the system load indicator graphs:

[image]

It definitely belongs to the load indicator application, but I'm desperate in finding what parameter adds and removes it.

Could someone point me to it please?

Comment: Same problem here, very annoying. Especially because the number of digits changes and the whole widget jumps horizontally

Comment: @danza could you try going to preferences -> Indicator items... -> and remove everything from the list? It helped me

Comment: Yeah that's it! Thanks a lot! Why don't you answer to your question? So i could upvote your answer! :)

Comment: @danza done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like to remove it one need to remove all the items from `preferences -> Indicator items`.